# Отправка данных через Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

не силен в Ajax и проблема такова, имеется авторизация в которой данные с формы идут через ajax, всё отлично, ошибок нет, создал другую форму, но при нажатии на кнопку сразу ошибка токена, как можно исправить?

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'no_ajax') {
        return;
    }
    var json;
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(result) {
            json = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            if (json.url) {
                window.location.href = '/' + json.url;
            } else {
                alert(json.status + ' - ' + json.message);
            }
        },
    });
});
});
```

**Рабочая форма**

```
      <div class="main">
    <div class="auth">
    <form action="/account/login" method="post">
            <p>Login:</p><input type="text" name="login" class="auth_inp" placeholder="Login" 
value='admin'><br>
            <p class="p_pass">Password:</p><input type="text" name="password" class="auth_inp" 
placeholder="Password" value='admin'><br>
            <button type="submit" class="but">Sign in</button>
        </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Не рабочая форма**

```
<div class="main">
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="h2">Info</h2>
  <a href="index" ><img src="/public/styles/img/back.png" width="25" height="25" alt="back" 
style="position:absolute;margin-top:-25px; margin-left: 70px;"></a>
  <form action="/miners/miner" method="POST">
      <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="str"  value="start">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="stp" value="stop">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="res" value="restart">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="reb" value="reboot">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="add" value="add/change">
        <input type="submit" class="but btn-reset" name="fil" value="filter">
      </div>

    <div class="title">
    <span class="descr">Description</span>
    <span class="descr">Status</span>
    <span class="descr">Progress</span>
    <span class="descr">Perfomanse</span>
    <span class="descr">Info</span>
  </div>
<?php foreach ($data as $val): ?>
  <div class="Info">
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="<? echo $val['id']; ?>">
    <div class="func"><a href="/info/asic/<? echo $val['owner']; ?>"><? echo $val['name'] ?> 
 </a></div>
</div>
</form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div></div></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что пхп-то в ответ на эту форму возвращает? небось пару килобайт HTML-а? Надо уже научиться хотя бы внешне отличать джейсон от хтмл

Comment: @Ипатьев, Верно, html, а как в json преобразовать? Не работал толком с JS к сожалению

Comment: никак. надо сначала для себя определиться, что вы делаете и зачем.

Comment: Как минимум, не подсовывайте шаблон или html в ответ? Хотите получать JSON — надо отдать JSON, желательно с заголовком, например, `header('Content-Type: application/json'); echo json_encode($data);`